# group by and delete documents based on a field array size

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53bcedc39c837bba3e1bf1c2"),
    id : "abc1",
    someArray: [ 1 , 10 , 11]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53bcedc39c837bba3e1bf1c4"),
    id : "abc1",
    someArray: [ 1 , 10]
}
... other similar documents with different Ids
```

I would like to go through the whole collection and delete the document where `someArray` is smallest, grouped by `id`. So in this example, I group by `abc1` (and I get 2 documents) and then the 2nd document would be the one to delete because it has least count in `someArray`.

There isn't a `$count` accumulator so I don't see how I can use `$group`.

Additionally, there will be 1000s of Ids that have duplicates like this, so if there is such a thing as a bulk check/delete that would be good (possibly a stupid question, sorry, Mongo is all new to me!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing "duplicates" is a process here and there is no simple way to both "identify" the dupliciates and "remove" them as a single statement. Another particular here is that query forms cannot "typically" determine the size of an array, and certainly cannot sort by that where it is not already present in the document.

All cases basically come down to

1. Identifying the list of documents that are "duplicates", and then ideally fingering the particular document you want to delete, or more to the point the document you "don't" want to delete from the possible duplicates.
2. Processing that list to actually perform the deletes.

With that in mind you hopefully have a modern MongoDB of 2.6 version or greater where you can obtain a cursor from the [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method. You also want the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) available in these versions for optimal speed:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "id": 1,
        "size": { "$size": "$someArray" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "id": 1, "size": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "docId": { "$first": "$_id" }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "id": doc._id, "_id": { "$ne": doc.docId }).remove();
    counter++;

    // Send to server once every 1000 statements only
    if ( counter % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();  // need to reset
    }
});

// Clean up results that did not round to 1000
if ( counter % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

You can still do much the same thing with older versions of MongoDB, but the result from `.aggregate()` must be under 16MB which is the BSON limit. That still should be a lot, but with older versions you could also output to a collection with mapReduce.

But for the general aggregation response, you get an array of results and you also don't have the other convienience methods for finding the size of the array. So a little more work:

```js
var result = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$someArray" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "id": { "$first": "$id" },
        "size": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "id": 1, "size": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "docId": { "$first": "$_id" }
    }}
]);

result.result.forEach(function(doc) {
    db.collection.remove({ "id": doc._id, "_id": { "$ne": doc.docId } });
});
```

So no cursor for large results and no bulk operations so every single "remove" needs to be sent to the server individually.

So in MongoDB there are no "sub-queries" or even when there is more than "two duplicates" a way to single out the document you don't want to remove from the other duplicates. But this is the general way to do it.

Just as a note, if the "size" of arrays is something important to you for a purpose such as "sorting", then your best apporach is to maintain that "size" as another property of your document so it makes those operations easier without needing to "calculate" that as is done here.